# How do I print the output in one row below another?

Tags: c#

For example I am trying to print the output in following way:
disk: 1    2     3     4     5
move: 1    3     7     15    31
How can I do that, can someone help me out please?

```
{
    class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 2;

        for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
            Console.WriteLine("disk: {0}", j);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)                               
                Console.WriteLine("moves: {2:N0}",
                                  n, i,(long)Math.Pow(n, i) - 1);

    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Console.Write` and it wont print a carriage return.

However you dont need a for loop in this case.  Just use `Enumerable.Range`

```
  var n = 2;
  var disks = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).ToList();
  var moves = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(i => (long) Math.Pow(n, i) - 1);
  Console.WriteLine("disk: {0}", string.Join(" ", disks));
  Console.WriteLine("moves: {0:N0}", string.Join(" ", moves));
```

Results:

> `disk: 1 2 3 4 5
>   moves: 1 3 7 15 31`

Comment: Understood. And this is pretty simple to understand as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`Console.WriteLine` will, as it sounds, write a new line each time.  If you don't want that behavior, use `Console.Write`.

```
Console.Write("Disk:");
for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
     Console.Write(" {0}", j);
Console.WriteLine();

Console.Write("Moves:");
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)                               
     Console.Write(" {2:N0}", (long)Math.Pow(n, i) - 1);
Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this made more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `string.PadLeft()` method to justify your text. Of course you can replace the magic numbers with a constant value. This gives you the advantage of not having to count spaces, and automatically adds the right amount of spaces to bring the string up to the desired length.

Note that you can also get rid of the format insertion (i.e. no more curly braces).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int power = 2;

    Console.Write("disk:".PadLeft(8));
    for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
        Console.Write(j.ToString().PadLeft(5));

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("moves:".PadLeft(8));
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        Console.Write(((long)Math.Pow(power, i) - 1).ToString().PadLeft(5));


    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I haven't heard of PadLeft till now, this is awesome. Thank you so much.